# multi-label classification and its definition

Tags: classification

can someone simply tell me what is the definition of multi-label classification please?
I have always seen data which are 'x' or 'y'.
what does it mean when we say it is multi-label classification??

Comment: Suppose you're given audio clips containing bird calls. You know that the calls can from from any of ten different birds. Which specific birds' calls are present in a given clip?

Answer (score 0):

**Single label classification** :  each example belong just 1 class

**Multilabel classification** : each instance can belong to more than one class

Please mark my answer if it is usefull for you. I need pointS since i can not comment : (